# infinite tense or gerund in this case?

Tags: verbs, sequence-of-tenses

Should I use the infinite tense or the gerund in this case?

> It was so distressing **seeing/to see** Jack kill his neighbour.

If both are correct, is there a difference in formality?

Comment: There's no difference in meaning, syntactic "correctness", or "level of formality", but on purely stylistic grounds we'd normally avoid using two consecutive ***-ing*** forms like this with significantly different syntactic roles. So it's usually *interesting **to know*** unusual facts, rather than *interesting **knowing** them*.

Comment: We could say that the infinitival implies that we saw the whole event of his neighbour's being killed, while the gerund-participial has a progressive meaning implying that we saw only a segment of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either works, and the meaning is much the same. Nor is one more formal than the other. The use of "seeing" perhaps gives a greater sense of immediacy and involvement in the events. In short the difference is one of style.  I do think the version with "seeing" might be better recast as

> Seeing Jack kill his neighbour was very distressing.

This emphasizes the sight of the killing more, and the immediate repetition of the "ing" ending in "so distressing seeing" seems awkward to me.